# SQL Server to Azure Cosmos DB Migration

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-sql-server

Please let me know whether we can migrate stored procedure from Microsoft SQL server to Microsoft Azure Cosmos DB ? 
Either with DocumentDB migration tool or any other tool

Answer (score 2):

There's really no direct correlation between the two: Stored procedures within the two databases are completely different. No possible way to migrate them, aside from you doing a complete rewrite. SQL Server stored procedures are written in SQL, vs Cosmos DB's JS-based stored procedures. Plus there is the notion of partitions, context, etc.

And Cosmos DB doesn't offer SQL Server compatibility and isn't a relational database. The Core (SQL) API takes advantage of SQL query language, but only for queries.

Comment: Clear answer.@SumethMK You could accept it to end this case.